# A word to say many things should be done together

Tags: word-request

> They can be displayed ...(together/ all in once ?).... for visual comparison

When you want to say something are displayed or processed or done together..

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most choices in JMB's answer; however, I would personally phrase it differently.

> They can be displayed ____ for visual comparison.

Instead of emphasizing on "when" (as in "all together", or "all at once"), I believe that emphasizing on "how" makes the sentence flow better, and clearer. For example,

> *They can be displayed **on the same page** for visual comparison.*
>   *They can be displayed **in the same window** for visual comparison.*
>   *They can be displayed **side by side** for visual comparison.*
>   *They can be displayed **next to each other** for visual comparison.* (if there are two of them)
>   *They can be displayed **next to one another** for visual comparison.*  (more than two)

If the verb is "process", I would use a different word, *simultaneously*.

> *These tasks will be processed **simultaneously**.*

Answer (score 1):

They can be displayed

> All together
>
> In a group
>
> In a row
>
> All in one area

They can be processed

> At once
>
> In one go
>
> All together

Comment: Agreed. Except that "in one go" is idiomatic in BrE but not in AmE.

Answer (score -2):

Concomitantly- at the same time; simultaneously

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to provide more details? How is this used? In what contexts? Also, a reference would be helpful.